# ¿factorial de un numero sin que se desborde la variable long?

Tags: java, variables, método

tengo un código que realiza permutaciones,y en un principio parece funcionar, el problema es que cuando ingresas un numero mayor a 20 salen erróneos los resultados y según eh leído y es porque salen tantos caracteres de resultado que no son posibles de almacenarlos todos en la variable de tipo long, mi pregunta es si es posible hacer que no se desborde la variable long o si hay una variable que permita almacenar un numero tan grande.

les agradecería muchísimo que me ayudaran, también acepto sugerencias si es que ven algo mal en mi código.

gracias.

```
try {
        int vn = Integer.parseInt(tn.getText());
        int vr = Integer.parseInt(tr.getText());
        long rvn = vn;
        int rr = vn - vr;
        long rvr = rr;
        long resultado;
        if (rr == 0 || rr == 1) {
            rr = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < vn; i++) {
                rvn = rvn * i;
            }
            resultado = rvn / rr;
            tre.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i < vn; i++) {
                rvn = rvn * i;
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < rr; i++) {
                rvr = rvr * i;
            }
            resultado = rvn / rvr;
            tre.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
        }
        tr.setText(null);
        tn.setText(null);
    } catch (NumberFormatException as) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Solo Puedes Ingresar Numeros", "Error", ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Si no te importa perder precisión podrías usar un double.

Comment: la precisión es importante en esta caso, asi el codigo muestra el resultado correcto usando numero pequeños, pero ya ingresando uno mayor a 20 salen incorrectos.

Comment: El código del bloque `if (rr == 0 || rr == 1)` parece tener varias cosas innecesarias. Si `rr == 0`, `rvn` también lo será y no tiene sentido el `for`. Y `rr` será siempre 1, no tiene sentido dividir por `rr`. Es mejor usar `*=` para que quede claro que estás multiplicando el mismo valor y no otro. Por último, sería conveniente ponerle nombres más claros a las variables, porque los actuales no lo son. Puede que los recuerdes hoy, pero en un tiempo cuando veas el código nada tendrá sentido, como en este momento le sucede a casi todos los que leemos tu código.

Comment: muchas gracias por las observaciones, las tomare en cuenta y tratare de implementarlas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase `BigIntegrer` definida en el paquete java.math.

`import java.math.BigInteger;`

Si quieres información de como utilizarlo aqui tienes un tutorial (en inglés)
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/DomathoperationforBigInteger.htm

Comment: he leído sobre lo que me comentaste y si que resolvería el problema , pero no logro implementarlo, me salen muchos errores, seguiré leyendo e intentándolo,pero si pudieras ayudarme a implementarlo te lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: @DiegoMontiel me gustaría, pero tal y como están los nombres de las variables, me cuesta entender que hace el código en si.

Comment: Gracias Adrian, con lo poco que has comentado, he podido solucionar mi problema, solo bastaba cambiar el tipo de variable por `BigInteger`

Answer (score 1):

lo que hice para poder realizar la duda que tenia, fue crear un metodorecursivo  de tipo BigInteeger, donde lo que hace es sacar el factorial de un numero, como dije arriba, con el método que tenia la variable de tipo long se desvorbada, pero leyendo un poco eh implementado la clase `Math` con el tipo de varibale `BigInteger` y de esta forma me sale el valor correcto sin limitacion.

```
 public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
//por definicion el factorial de 0 y de 1 es 1.
    if(n.equals(BigInteger.ONE)||n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    //si no es 1 o 0 hace la operación.
    return n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```

ya teniendo el metodo recursivo que permiria sacar el factorial de cualquier numero sin restriccion, ya soo me quedo realizar las operaciones correspondientes con esos resultados y quedo asi.

```
try {
        BigInteger vn = new BigInteger(tn.getText());
        BigInteger vr = new BigInteger(tr.getText());
        BigInteger rr = vn.subtract(vr);
        BigInteger rfn = factorial(vn);
        BigInteger rfr = factorial(vr);
        BigInteger rfrr = factorial(rr);
        BigInteger rrr = rfr.multiply(rfrr);
        BigInteger resultado = rfn.divide(rrr);
        tre.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
        tn.setText(null);
        tr.setText(null);
    } catch (NumberFormatException r) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Solo Puedes Ingresar Numeros", "Error", ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```